# Count of the number of appointments that each customer has made - Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregation

I am trying to create a SQL query in Microsoft access that is able to count of the number of
appointments that each customer has made but have been unsuccessful so far. I have two separate tables, one for appointment and one for customers as listed below.

Appointment

[image]

Customer

[image]

Comment: What does 'unsuccessful' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Edit question to show attempted query. This should be a simple aggregate query.

Comment: You have been on this site long enough to know that this is quite inadequate. What have you tried? What is going wrong? What errors do you get? This is a very simple join with a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do some aggregation:

```
SELECT Customer.Customer_ID, Customer.Name, Customer.Lastname, COUNT(*)
FROM Customer
JOIN Appointment
ON Customer.Customer_ID = Appointment.Customer_ID
WHERE Attended <> 'Yes'
GROUP BY Customer.Customer_ID, Customer.Name, Customer.Lastname;
```

I have no MS Access in front of me, so if there is a typo, let me know!

Comment: Possibly "unsuccessful" was referring to effort to build query and not to customer attendance.

Comment: @June7 regardless of what has been unsuccessful, the query that needs to be executed is a join with a group by.

Comment: I would have assumed that Attended was a Boolean field (YesNo in Access) not a text. There again I read the question exactly as June7 did. Can we please close this?